# Bluetooth inputs form wireless devices

Tags: python, bluetooth

I have a pair of Bluetooth earbuds that have touch capabilities to pause and play music and it works fine on my win 10 pc. So, I am trying to make a small python script that triggers an event on receiving signals from the earbuds as I had heard that python 3.9 now supports Bluetooth for windows 10. So is there any way to receive those signals in python? I have tried wire shark but it does not detect any Bluetooth devices at all .

What I have tried:

- pybluez (doesn't work for win 10)
- sockets (it requires a client program installed on the other device which is not possible)

Comment: language does not support devices per se, its just implementation that host machine supports.

Comment: @Debendra but I'm sure that my machine supports communication both ways as the pause/play feature works just fine... I just want to intercept those signals and trigger events based on them...

Comment: As far as I am aware the Bluetooth support added in Python 3.9 for Windows is for Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP). The headphones are likely to be using A2DP or HFP. More details on the different Bluetooth profiles at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/

Comment: Thanks, @ukBaz .I checked, mine used AVRCP. Does that make a difference?